# $this->db->insert_id(); returning 0 every time in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and inserting one record at a time. But the problem is that $this->db->insert_id(); is returning 0 every time, however record is getting created successfully. I am unable to figure it out. Is this usual case or I am doing some silly mistake. I have used email_id as primary key and mobile no as unique.

Here is my code of modal:

```
function signup_insert($data) {

        $result = $this->db->insert('registration_detail', $data);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $insert_id;
    }
```

And this is my code of controller:

```
function insert_signup() {
        $email = $this->input->get('email');
        $name = $this->input->get('name');
        $password1 = $this->input->get('password1');
        $password2 = $this->input->get('password2');
        $phone = $this->input->get('phone');
        $country = $this->input->get('country');

        $data = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $name,
            'pwd' => $password1,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'country' => $country
        );

        $insert_id = $this->signup->signup_insert($data);
        print_r($insert_id);
    }
```

Comment: I just did, it is still returning 0 every time.

Comment: What DB are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Yes, it is $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

Comment: Print insert id within `signup_insert()` then you will know whether it is being generated and not being returned or whether it is not being generated at all

Comment: This must be a problem with your mysql, as insert_id() for Mysql uses the `mysql_insert_id` function. Do you have an *AUTO_INCREMENT* row?

Comment: Post your table structure !!!

Comment: No, as I mentioned I am using email_id as primary key, there is no AUTO INCREMENT row.

Comment: that's the problem because `$this->db->insert_id()` return

**The insert ID number when performing database inserts.**

Comment: So how can I check whether data has been inserted successfully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hence `$this->db->insert_id()`

> The insert ID number when performing database inserts.

And there is no auto incremented id in your database

TO check data is insert or not use

```
$this->db->affected_rows()
```

> Displays the number of affected rows, when doing "write" type queries
>   (insert, update, etc.).

**Models**

```
function signup_insert($data) {
    $result = $this->db->insert('registration_detail', $data);
    $rows =  $this->db->affected_rows();
    if($rows>0){
    return $rows;
    }else{
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Read http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: Short note: in CodeIgniter4 its affectedRows() instead of affected_rows().

Answer (score 3):

To return a id it there should be a AUTO_INCREMENT column. If not it cannot return a insert_id, see mysql documentation here..

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html