# Codeigniter $this->db->insert_id() returning 0 on mysqli but $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()') works

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

This is my database config:-

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test_db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

I insert user using this and output last id on `die();`

```
$this->db->insert("user",$data);
$lastid=$this->db->insert_id();
die($lastid);`
```

It outputted `0`

But when I use:-

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = $query->row_array();
$lastid= $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
die($lastid);
```

It outputted the last inserted id...

I have an `auto_increment` on `user_id`

Why `$this->db->insert_id()` wont work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655723/this-db-insert-id-returning-0-every-time-in-codeigniter

Comment: https://kedyr.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/codeigniter-insert_id/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the link what i have given to you (in comments):-

1.From the first link([$this->db->insert_id(); returning 0 every time in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655723/this-db-insert-id-returning-0-every-time-in-codeigniter)) You may be don't have an primary-key auto-incremented column. So you can then use:-

```
$this->db->affected_rows()
```

(But this will not give you the last inserted id, it will tell you how many rows are affected because of insert query)

2.From the second link(https://kedyr.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/codeigniter-insert_id/) exactly the same solution is given what you have tried in your second attempt(which is working for you),but there is no explanation given why this behavior is occurring.

3.based on :- http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61881.html

*MySQLi resets the insert id upon committing the transaction (intended behaviour). When it's without a transaction, I think that behaviour differed between PHP versions, due to a bug. Try wrapping it in a transaction, by calling trans_begin(), then the insert(), then the insert_id(), then commit().*

But i think that is a very high-end concept (even i have no idea how to perform this, so no comments).

4.from this link:- https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/591
Again it is saying:-

a.**If there was no auto_increment column it would return 0**

b.**No mysqli connection/link id would return false(which is actually 0 in php).**

Lastly once try with this:-

```
$this->db->insert("user",$data);
$lastid=$this->db->insert_id();
echo $lastid;die;
```

Comment: I have auto increment though but it still not working.
$this->db->insert_id() worked before though I think I'll use the second option
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = $query->row_array();
$lastid= $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
die($lastid);
Still wondering why $this->db->insert_id() wont work.

Comment: what about  `$this->db->affected_rows()`  or the last one what i suggested?

Comment: @Vlanzyvinz  i am wondering  too (not because it's not working, because of no explanation is given for this)

Comment: I'll try $this->db->affected_rows()
I just tried `db->trans_start()` `db->trans_complete();`
`$this->db->trans_start();<br>
$this->db->insert("uhd_voucher_menu",$data);<br>
$lastid=$this->db->insert_id();<br>
$this->db->trans_complete();<br>
die($lastid);`
Still dont get the id

Comment: @Vlanzyvinz  what about the last one. `echo $lastid;die;` ?

Comment: $this->db->affected_rows() is not for returning last insert ID, 
Its purpose is to return the affected row, so if I insert one row then it will return 1, or when altering 2 rows then it will return 2 I think

Comment: @Vlanzyvinz  yes i know that. it's for checking purpose(sorry i didn't mentioned)

Comment: About echo $last_id;die; it worked, it echoed the id both your answer about to get the last_id you guys give me worked.
die($last_id); didnt output the last_id to screen (dont know why).
Thank you Anant for the explanation, and to Akhil

Answer (score 3):

I have checked and it works fine.Please try it like this

```
public function addNewAdmin($data) {

        $result = $this->db->insert("admins", $data);
        $lastid=$this->db->insert_id();        
        echo $lastid;exit;        
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to wrap those stuff inside a function(i am not criticizing just curious because i have very very less knowledge of CI)

Comment: that function supposed to be inside a model class.
because CI is MVC.
then on controller we can call the model by $this->Model_name->addNewAdmin($data);

Comment: No its not necessary to write this inside a function.As written by @vlanzyvinz it is used in model that why i have written it inside a function to access this function directly in controller.

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->insert_id() returns the id of the last row where the insert was made, Making sure you have set you id column as the primary key to auto increment. use this;

```
$this->db->insert('table',$array(''=>,));
$id=$this->db->insert_id();`enter code here`
return $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the id is not being returned because your auto incremental value is not just plain ID but user_id.. this is because I tried

```
$this->db->insert("user",$data);
$lastid=$this->db->insert_id();
die($lastid);
```

With a table which had ID and it worked but when I tried it with a table with item_id in the same project that did not work